# Request JSON from existDB

Tags: jquery, json, exist-db

I am rather new to eXistDB but I'm trying to build a little app with it.

I am using a JavaScript example that requests an existing JSON file via jQuery when needed with the following code:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/file.json').
    done(function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, zone) {
            addRegion(zone, element);
        });
    });
```

This worked regardless of eXistDB as long as the JSON file is present. What I want now, is not to load an existing JSON file, but to call an eXist function like app:getJSON which returns a dynamically genereated JSON object. I read a bit about eXists JSON serializer here http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/XQuery31 and I *think* I will manage to produce and return a JSON object in a XQuery function, but I do not know how to call such a function via URL from my JavaScript (or here JQuery).

My desired solution would look somewhat like this:

Java Script:

```
 $.getJSON('/app-getJSON?parameter1=wert1&parameter2=wert2').
    done(function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, zone) {
            addRegion(zone, element);
        });
    });
```

and then in my app.xql I would want to have something like:

```
declare function app:getJSON($node as node(), $model as map(*), $parameter1 as xs:string?, $parameter2 as xs:string?){
    (:here the JSON Object is generated from the XML collection and returned:)
};
```

So the question comes down to: Is it possible to access a xQuery function via URL and if so, how? If not, how else can I request JSON data that is generated from my XML files with JS/JQuery? I know this is all pretty vague and the question gives away how new I am to eXistDB but I can't find a similar example that I would understand yet. So maybe someone has an idea for me, even if it's only a "you should really read this, this and this" first. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating a service that returns JSON I would advise creating a standalone XQuery, e.g., `getJSON.xq`, and saving this in your application. (Your sample `app:getJSON()` function's signature suggested you were planning to use eXist's HTML templating facility, but that facility is really meant for generating HTML.) Your `getJSON.xq` file could simply consist of the following main module:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method "json";
declare option output:media-type "application/json";

let $p1 := request:get-parameter('parameter1', ())
let $p2 := request:get-parameter('parameter2', ())
return
    map {
        "parameter1": $p1,
        "parameter2": $p2
    }
```

Saving this to a collection like `/db/apps/getJSON.xq`, you will then be able to call http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp/getJSON.xq?parameter1=wert1&parameter2=wert2 and get the following response:

```
{
    "parameter1" : "wert1",
    "parameter2" : "wert2"
}
```

Note: This code assumes eXist v3.x, which added handling for XQuery 3.1's JSON support. Earlier versions of eXist could serialize JSON, but in an implementation-specific way. The `request` module used here is eXist-specific, since there is no widely supported cross platform module for receiving HTTP requests; other XQuery implementations have some variant though.

Comment: Sorry for only replying now, I did't go on with this project for quite a while due to very limited time. Perfect solution, exactly what I wanted :D

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!

Comment: I got into a situation now, where I have dozens of these xq files of which each is only doing one small task such as "update this xml file in the collection" or "copy this xml file from here to there". I would like to store them as a module where each of the tasks is a function and then again... call these functions assyncronously via JavaScript. But how? I mean: is there anything that "maps" http requests to xquery functions somehow?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for RESTXQ. If you put your various functions in a library module (e.g., `/db/apps/my-app/my-module.xqm`), you can add RESTXQ annotations to your functions to make them URL endpoints. For a starter template, see https://gist.github.com/joewiz/28dd9b8454d14b4164a0. For the spec, see http://exquery.github.io/exquery/exquery-restxq-specification/restxq-1.0-specification.html.

Comment: Ha, I thought so yesterday after searching the problem but then I couldn't understand the eXist demo apps on RESTXQ because one uses XForms/BetterForm and the other one uses angular.js... both too much to work myself into for one evening. Thanks for your starter template, I guess that's all I need to begin with. Found some slides by Retter, too but it's nice to have a working starting point here :D  Thanks a lot!

Comment: yet another question (thanks for helping): I can't get the template to run. I put it into /db/apps/superapp/restxq-template.xqm. I made sure that /db/apps/superapp/collection.xconf has the trigger set. I restarted eXist (no idea if that is neccessary) but how do I call hello() via URL now? no matter how I tried it, I always get something like: "HTTP ERROR 405

Problem accessing /exist/restxq/index.html/hello. Reason:

    HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"    restxq.log does not contain any entry for today. I must miss something